# Multi languages resources with proper language code

Tags: android, resources, locale, translation, iso

I want to make application, that will support languages with resources depending of actual localization and country  code. According to [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources) I need to change resources to format i.e. `values-en-rUS`, and in that configuration app sucessful compile and proper flag image in resources is set it up but I dont know what format should be write in `Locale` variable to change resources. I try  `en_US` ,  `en-rUS` , `en-US` but does doesnt work correctly. In my previous version with resources like `values-en` changing `Locale` of the app language  to `en` the resources are updating correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locale for `values-en-rUS` can be obtained by `new Locale("en", "US")`, this will get instance of "en_US" locale (matching `values-en-rUS`).

Don't use `new Locale("en_US")` this will produce "en_us". That doesn't match `values-en-rUS`. Also `new Locale("en-US")` will not work.

From API level 21, there's handy `Locale.forLanguageTag(String)` method. It returns a locale for the specified IETF BCP 47 language tag string, which is "en-US" in this case. So you can use `Locale.forLanguageTag("en-US)`.

Answer (score 0):

Not totaly sure of what you asking but if you want to add languages you need to create indeed to create the write folder but in that format : `<resource type>-b+<language code>[+<country code>]` 
example : `value-b+en+US`

Then you can add the `strings.xml` file in each folder to what you want to display. You can find all the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).